# (Simple) model of product prices dependend on demand and stock (partly solved)

Tags: calculus

Model:

```
CityA has a demand of X amount of a product per week, and pays Y money (up 
to a set min and max amount) for each item, depending on the amount already 
in stock.
Example: 10 Items/Week, max price 100, min price 25 (rough estimate: 
products for 1 week in stock -> price=65, 2 weeks -> 45, 3 weeks -> 35, 4 
weeks -> 30,..)

[This model is for example used in the trading simulation game Patrician 
2/3, where you buy/sell different goods, and the price the city is paying 
you for each good is dependend on how much they need it and how much they 
already have it in stock]
```

My approach:

$$P(x) = p_{max}\cdot c_1\cdot exp(-c_2 \cdot x)+p_{min}, c_1/c_2\in \mathbb R $$
with $$P(x)=\text{Price at x% demand saturation}$$ , $$x=\frac{\text{stock}}{\text{demand per week}}$$ (so how much of the weekly needed items are already in stock / demand saturation),   $$p_{max}/p_{min} = \text{max/min product price paid by CityA}$$.

I set  $$p_{min}= c_3 \cdot p_{max} , c_3 \in \mathbb R$$ and get:

$$P(x) = p_{max}\cdot c_1\cdot exp(-c_2 \cdot x)+p_{max}*c_3$$

The Equation needs to satisfy $$P(0)=p_{max}$$ so i set $$c_1:=(1-c_3) $$$$\to P(x) = p_{max}\cdot ((1-c_3)\cdot exp(-c_2 \cdot x)+c_3) $$

Now i tweaked the values for $c_2$ and $c_3$ with $$c_2=0.65,c_3=0.25$$ for my intended prices, which gives the following graph for $p_{max}=100$ (with values for P(x), x=0,0.5,1,2,3,4,1000):

$$\to P(x) = 100\cdot (0.75\cdot exp(-0.65 \cdot x)+0.25)$$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB7Pu.png

Missing:

with this formula for $P(x)$ i can calculate the price of **1** product, depending on the demand saturation, but: how do i calculate **multiple** sales at once? So 2,5,10 or n sales. The total price of n products at once should be  the same as n sales of 1 product one after another; the problem is the demand saturation will change after a single product is sold. A simple (dumb) approach would be to calculate $$\sum_{i=0}^n P(\frac{ItemsInStock+i}{DemandPerWeek}), n =Number of Sales$$ (i think thats correct), but that doesnt seem elegant or practical, i want a single formula for this (for say i want so sell 1,000,000,000,000 products)

My maths knowledge goes into university level (bachelor) maths , but right know i dont have a starting point what kind of problem i have here.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction!

Comment: Could you specify what the symbols are in your post? It's a good idea to always write something along the lines "Let's set $x$ is blabla bla and $p$ is bla bla bla ...".

Comment: @Matti P. i added example values and more explanations for used symbols

Comment: and i have to add that english is not my first language, so it might be not as clear as it could be